# Keeping the current orientation

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-dialogfragment, android-orientation, orientation-changes

My app does the following:

1. I take a picture
2. The picture is displayed in a DialogFragment

If I take the picture in landscape mode, I want the orientation of the DialogFragment which is showing my image to be locked to landscape mode. 
If I take the image in portrait mode, I would like the orientation of the DialogFragment be locked to portrait mode.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the width and height of your image, that should be enough to tell you wether it was taken in portrait or landscape mode. Set your orientation with

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

or

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

And if you want to re-enable your auto-rotate functions at a later time just use

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```